# Unable to route to a method in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I’m trying to set up my controller so that when a logged in user visits /users/edit, they see my form where they can edit some of their profiles.  So in config/routes.rb I have

```
  resources :users
  …
  get "users/edit" => "users#edit"
```

then in “app/controllers/users_controller.rb” I have

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    render 'edit' 
  end
```

but when I visit “http://localhost:3000/users/edit” in a browser, I get the error

```
The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

It is true I have no “show” method in my controller, but that is not where I want the user to go.  I want them going to the edit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing a resource route with your own edit method, and ["Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) so it's matching the resources show route `users/:id` and stopping there.

You need to move your edit route above the resource.

Alternatively, read the linked guide and see if you can add edit as a collection route to the resource, and `except` the resources edit method. You may also need to except the show method, but it's worth having a play and seeing what you come up with. Routing is an important aspect and worth time to understand.

Comment: K, I did this and I'm getting a different error but I think it has nothing to do with what you suggested.  I'll come back and accept this after i work out the other error.  Thanks, -

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to go to the show action with this link:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/edit
```

You have this route for the show action:

```
GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

`(:id)` is `(edit)`

Because you have defined first RESTful route:

```
resources :users
```

Which includes all routes listed below:

```
users_path      GET       /users(.:format)           users#index
                POST      /users(.:format)           users#create
new_user_path   GET       /users/new(.:format)       users#new
edit_user_path  GET       /users/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
user_path       GET       /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
                PATCH     /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
                PUT       /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
                DELETE    /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
```

and then

```
get "users/edit" => "users#edit"
```

Rails always finds first match. In this case show action of RESTFul routes  will be applied:

```
GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

and the other route will be ignored.

**Solution:**  Change the order of the routes. That way edit route will be applied first.

Answer (score -1):

remove `get "users/edit" => "users#edit"` from your routes, change to `resources :users, only: [:edit]` (or more if actions you need them), remove the `render 'edit'` from your controller (default action).

Visit `http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit` to see the edit page for user_id 1 (there can't be an edit page for all users, you have to specify the id)

Comment: I don't want to specify "http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit", I want to specify "http://localhost:3000/users/edit" and I want to be able to edit the fields of the current, logged in user.

Comment: Then you need to have it route to the edit page with the current users id. Right after they finish logging in you probably have something like `redirect_to edit_user_path`, you need to give that a user id (or just the whole user object). So `redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)`

Comment: @matt That's how routing is supposed to work... Going against that is going against rails convention

Comment: @RoccoBasso Conventions != restrictions, if the poster want to expose an edit method for the current user without exposing their id why shouldn't that be done? Devise - a popular authentication gem - [does exactly this!](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)